# Display the Contacts in sorting order ContactsContract.Contacts of Content Resolver

Tags: android, android-contentresolver

My intention is to display the contacts in **sorting order** using `content resolver` in android.

For that I'm writing:

```
Cursor pCur = cr.query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null,
                            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID+ " = ?", new String[] { id }, null);
```

It needs that the last parameter in query method should not be null for sorting the elements by `Name`. Which part of code I have to replace the null parameter to achieve sorting by name?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

To sort result according to name use `Phone.DISPLAY_NAME` constant with `ASC` as last parameter to `query` method. do it as:

```
  Cursor pCur = cr.query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, 
                   null, 
                   ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID+ " = ?",
                   new String[] { id },
                   ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME+" ASC");
```

Comment: Do you happen to know where the list of different values of the constants for sorting can be found. I assume "DEC" may be the other way around but what about other forms of sorting?

Comment: what is {id} here?

Comment: @NVA it's "DESC" for descending

Answer (score 15):

It would be better to use [SORT_KEY_PRIMARY](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.ContactNameColumns.html#SORT_KEY_PRIMARY) or [SORT_KEY_ALTERNATIVE](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.ContactNameColumns.html#SORT_KEY_ALTERNATIVE) on API level 11 and later.

```
Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(
    ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI,
    null, null, null,
    ContactsContract.Contacts.SORT_KEY_PRIMARY + " ASC");
```

Comment: @Hamidreza are you sure? `SORT_KEY_PRIMARY`  has been introduced in API 11…

Comment: Great solution buddy

Answer (score 14):

You can use `Upper()` to sort for both lower as well as upper case contact name.

```
ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();

Cursor cur = cr.query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, null,
        null, null,  "upper("+ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME + ") ASC");
```

Comment: Does a standard sorting method (not using upper) give weight to uppercase letters? Like will names in all caps be BEFORE names in lowercase? If so, is that the reason behind your "upper(" line of code? If not, what does this do?

Answer (score 1):

The **ContentResolver.query()** method takes many arguments but to sort the content provider records, you have to edit the **last argument** of this method.

[image]

It should be like this:

`Cursor cursor=getContentProvider().query(.......,"DISPLAY_NAME ASC")`

This will arrange the contacts in Ascending order of their name.

*Note:* This argument should be in a String datatype.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Desc string using these lines to sort out to see the recent contact

```
    android.database.Cursor cursor = getContentResolver()
            .query(android.provider.ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI,
            null, null, null,
                    ContactsContract.Data.CONTACT_LAST_UPDATED_TIMESTAMP +" DESC");
```