# How to Sort Contact in Android

Tags: android, android-query

what are the keywords for sortting the query and how to use it

> Cursor cursor =
>   getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI,
>   null, null, null, null);

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13814786/display-the-contacts-in-sorting-order-contactscontract-contacts-of-content-resol

Answer (score 0):

Simply use ASC or DSC as last parameter to getContentResolver().query(......);
It will sort the fetch data accordingly. You can also use orderBy and other sorting methods same as in SQL