# arrange alphabetically contacts

Tags: android, listview

i retrieve the contacts from phone into listview,but they are apperaning in the unsorted way,i want to sort them..how it  is posible to soort them alphabatically .
i tried to use ASC after the display name bt it showdown the activity forcefully,what to do now..?

MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.smscampaign;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import android.app.ActionBar;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.ContentResolver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Parcelable;
import android.provider.ContactsContract;
import android.telephony.gsm.SmsManager;
import android.util.SparseBooleanArray;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.CompoundButton;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnItemClickListener {

    ArrayList<String> name1 = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String> phno1 = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String> phno0 = new ArrayList<String>();
    MyAdapter ma;
    Button send;
    ListView lv ;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
         ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
            actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        setContentView(R.layout.get);
        TextView txt=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        getAllCallLogs(this.getContentResolver());
        lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lv);
        ma = new MyAdapter();
        lv.setAdapter(ma);
        lv.setOnItemClickListener(this);
        lv.setItemsCanFocus(false);
        lv.setTextFilterEnabled(true);




    }

/*  @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPause();
        // Save ListView state
        Parcelable state = lv.onSaveInstanceState();

        // Set new items
        lv.setAdapter(Baseadapter);

        // Restore previous state (including selected item index and scroll position)
        lv.onRestoreInstanceState(state);
    }*/

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.contact_main, menu);

        return true;

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.addPage:

    break;

        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        StringBuilder checkedcontacts = new StringBuilder();
        System.out.println( ma.mCheckStates.size());
        for (int i = 0; i < name1.size(); i++)

        {
            if (ma.mCheckStates.get(i) == true) {
                phno0.add(phno1.get(i).toString());
                checkedcontacts.append(name1.get(i).toString());
                checkedcontacts.append("\n");

            } else {
                System.out.println("..Not Checked......"
                        + name1.get(i).toString());
            }

        } 
        //Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, checkedcontacts, 1000).show();
        Intent returnIntent = new Intent();
        returnIntent.putStringArrayListExtra("name", phno0);

        setResult(RESULT_OK, returnIntent);


        finish();
    }
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        ma.toggle(arg2);
    }

    public void getAllCallLogs(ContentResolver cr) {

        Cursor phones = cr.query(
                ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null, null,
                null, null);
        while (phones.moveToNext()) {
            String name = phones
                    .getString(phones
                            .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME));
            String phoneNumber = phones
                    .getString(phones
                            .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
            System.out.println(  phoneNumber);
            name1.add(name);
            phno1.add(phoneNumber);
        }

        phones.close();
    }

    class MyAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements
            CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener {
        private SparseBooleanArray mCheckStates;
        LayoutInflater mInflater;
        TextView tv1, tv;
        CheckBox cb;

        MyAdapter() {
            mCheckStates = new SparseBooleanArray(name1.size());
            mInflater = (LayoutInflater) MainActivity.this
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        }
         // Save ListView state

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return name1.size();
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int position) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return position;
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            return 0;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(final int position, View convertView,
                ViewGroup parent) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            View vi = convertView;
            if (convertView == null)
                vi = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.row, null);
            tv = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
            tv1 = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
            cb = (CheckBox) vi.findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);
            tv.setText(name1.get(position));
            tv1.setText( phno1.get(position));
            cb.setTag(position);
            cb.setChecked(mCheckStates.get(position, false));
            cb.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);

            return vi;
        }

        public boolean isChecked(int position) {
            return mCheckStates.get(position, false);
        }

        public void setChecked(int position, boolean isChecked) {
            mCheckStates.put(position, isChecked);
        }

        public void toggle(int position) {
            setChecked(position, !isChecked(position));
        }

        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,
                boolean isChecked) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            mCheckStates.put((Integer) buttonView.getTag(), isChecked);
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Have a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/a/13814897/206809. may can help you...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do somthing like...

```
Cursor phones = cr.query(
    ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, 
    ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME + " ASC");
```

Answer (score 2):

use this Cursor query hope it will help u :)

```
 Cursor c = cntx.getContentResolver().query(Contacts.CONTENT_URI, CONTACTS_SUMMARY_PROJECTION, select,
                        null, Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME + " COLLATE LOCALIZED ASC");
```